# What are these orientations called in orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, terminology

Let's say a spacecraft is in an orbit like this one:

[image]

If the red arrows point to prograde and retrograde, and the blue arrows point to normal and antinormal, **what do the green arrows point to?**

In other words, what does one call the orientations that are perpendicular to both the orbit prograde and the orbit normal?

Note that it's not necessarily correct to say "towards the planet" or "away from the planet."  In highly eccentric orbits like the one pictured above, both orientations can point "away."

Comment: In Kerbal Space Program they are often referred to as radial and anti-radial.

Comment: It seems to me that Nadir means "towards the planet", and Zenith "away from the planet", thus in directions not necessarily at 90 degrees to prograde/retrograde and port/starboard.  For the orthogonal directions is the similar direction, I've never seen a naming convention other than the above mentioned from KSP, with Radial and Anitiradial.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any generally agreed on convention, but spaceships are often regarded as, well, ships, so similar terms will be often used. E.g. for the red arrows that you describe as *prograde* and *retrograde* orientation vectors, from a spaceship's point of view and relative to its movement, also *ram-facing* and *wake-facing* is often used to describe sides, but could be also *forward* and *aft*, or even *bow* and *stern*. For the blue orientation vectors, these could then be *port* for *left* and *starboard* for *right*, relative to the vehicle's movement, facing forward. The green ones are most commonly called the *nadir* and *zenith* facing sides, but as the terminology varies depending on who's referring to it, I'd guess there's all kinds of other terms used too, from obvious *down*, *downward*, and *up*, *upward*, to *deck* and *overhead*, or even *towards* and *away* from something, in our case the body it orbits around. So for orientation relative to the ship's movement we have:

- ram-facing, forward, bow,...
- wake-facing, aft, stern,...
- starboard, right,...
- port, left,...
- nadir, deck, down, downward, towards *sth*,...
- zenith, overhead, up, upward, away *from sth*,...

For example, from [Reference guide to the International Space Station, Assembly complete edition, NASA 2010](http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/508318main_ISS_ref_guide_nov2010.pdf) (PDF), four of these sides are described in the definitions section as:

> - **nadir**: Direction directly below (opposite zenith)
> - **port**: Direction to the left side (opposite starboard)
> - **starboard**: Direction to the right side (opposite port)
> - **zenith**: Directly above, opposite nadir

And the remaining two sides mentioned in text as:

> **ram** (forward) or **wake** (aft) pointing

NASA's [Guide to the International Space Station Laboratory Racks Interactive](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/multimedia/iss_labs_guide.html) however names direction towards nadir as **deck** and direction towards zenith **overhead**, and alternatively also the +/- axial values that follow the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) more commonly used by astronaut pilots during navigation or to describe station's attitude (such as during docking):

[image]

<sup>Image above: The International Space Station’s coordinate system. Credit: [NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/multimedia/iss_labs_guide.html)</sup>

Alternatively, movement relative to these three axes could be described using [aviation terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_dynamics) *roll*, *pitch* and *yaw* to describe attitude of a satellite, but these don't really denote the sides, merely rotation of the body with respect to the x, y, z (in your case red, blue, green) axes in Cartesian coordinate system, respectively.

There might be other terms I didn't think of though, but as always, it will depend on who's using them and if they're referring to the sides from the perspective of the vessel and relative to its movement, or relative to some wider frame of reference, for example with respect to the body it orbits, in which case, alas, I fail to think of other ways these orientation sides could be named, short of describing them with respect to [orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements) in any of the various coordinate systems used, such as Keplerian, Cartesian,... like you did with *prograde* and *retrograde*, which are essentially broadly describing orbital inclination with respect to the body's plane of reference.

With specific spacecraft, often its sides are also named by its components or modules, which works irrespective of spacecraft's own movement relative to another object.

Comment: I'd be surprised if ship terms like port and starboard were used much on spaceships. Because a spaceship does not have a constant attitude relative to its motion vector, "port" can refer to the forward direction one moment, and the nadir direction the next.

Comment: Port and starboard are used extensively on the International Space Station, but then, the ISS generally holds a fixed attitude relative to its velocity vector.

Comment: @Hobbes If you look at [this image](http://www.esa.int/spaceinimages/Images/2008/07/Expedition_17_crewmember_Greg_Chamitoff_plays_a_game_of_chess_in_the_Harmony_Node_2_module_of_the_ISS) from inside the Harmony node, for example, you'll notice blue stickers with white text "PORT", "DECK", and "OVHD" for overhead. There's also a sticker with "STBD" for starboard that Greg Chamitoff blocks the view to. In Columbus lab (see e.g. first image [here](http://www.asc-csa.gc.ca/eng/astronauts/type_station.asp), there are also "FWD" for forward and "AFT" stickers due to its different orientation.

Comment: +1 for a good thorough answer.  I never heard ram/wake in actual use at JSC, just fwd/aft, but good to include them for completeness.

Comment: Port and starboard were used extensively in the shuttle as well. Here's a switch (pictured from a simulator) using them as labels. https://imgur.com/a/m6jpbin Note that the attitude of the ship is irrelevant - the port wing is still the port wing.

Answer (score 11):

There are 3 directions in any orbit. The typical convention is:

- Nadir- This is the direction towards the center of the planet, straight down. Oposite to NADIR is the Zenith.
- Velocity Vector- Direction of movement, Prograde/retrograde are a common, Prograde is the direction of orbit, retrograde opposite
- Normal direction to plane of orbit. This is often referred to as the angular momentum vector.

See also [this PDF](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~cdhall/courses/aoe4140/intro2adcs.pdf).

Comment: The zenith and nadir always go straight in and out of the planet's center, right?  So they're not necessarily perpendicular to the velocity vector?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the velocity vector is perpendicular to the planet's center in any case, at least for relatively uniform gravity objects, like all planets and most large moons.

Comment: I don't think so.  In the question diagram above, the green arrows miss the planet's center.  If the planet were smaller, they would miss it entirely.  The velocity vector (represented by the red arrows) is only tangential to the planet's surface if the orbit is perfectly circular or the spacecraft is at its periapsis or apoapsis.

Comment: For most orbital mechanics calculations, the green arrows will be aligned with the R-bar direction, i.e., pointing directly at the planet's center.  This does lead to a convention where the three axes are not mutually orthogonal, but the vector pointing to the planet center is more meaningful than an inward- or outward-pointing vector normal to the velocity vector.

Comment: @Nickolai, the radius and velocity vectors will only be orthogonal in a circular orbit.

Comment: The velocity vector is only perpendicular to the position vector for circular orbits or at apogee or perigee of elliptical orbits.

Answer (score 9):

In [Kerbal Space Program](https://kerbalspaceprogram.com/), they are called **Radial** and **Anti-Radial** on the Nav-Ball.

> **Radial and anti-radial**
>
> These vectors are parallel to the orbital plane, and perpendicular to the prograde vector. The radial (or radial-in) vector points inside the orbit, towards the focus of the orbit, while the anti-radial (or radial-out) vector points outside the orbit, away from the body. Performing a radial burn will rotate the orbit around the craft like spinning a hula hoop with a stick. Radial burns are usually not an efficient way of adjusting one's path - it is generally more effective to use prograde and retrograde burns. The maximum change in angle is always less than 90°; beyond this point the orbit would pass through the center of mass of the orbited body and the ship would traverse a slow spiral in towards the orbited body.
>
> - [KSP Wiki - Maneuver Node Directions](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Maneuver_node#Directions)

[image: KSP Symbol Gallery]

Comment: If you're curious about their use, I rarely use Radial/Anti-radial burns except during rendezvous with a mostly aligned but poorly timed trajectory as it allows me to 'catch up' or 'fall back' with respect to the other craft.

Comment: I came here to post the same thing! +1

Comment: prograde / retrograde are for changing periapsis / apoapsis altitudes. Normal / antinormal are for changing orbit inclination. Radial / antiradial are for moving periapsis and apoapsis around the orbit without changing their altitudes.

Answer (score 7):

The mathematical names for those directions are tangent (the red arrows), normal (the green arrows, and binormal (the blue arrows). Geometers have made extensive use of these, so much so that these directions are a key part of the Fundamental Theorem of Curves. For example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet-Serret_formulas, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofSpaceCurves.html, and http://math.rice.edu/~hardt/401F03/ftc.pdf.

This theorem isn't of much use in orbital mechanics because torsion involves a third derivative of position with respect to time. Orbital mechanics is a study of second derivatives: F=ma.

The directions along the red arrows (v-bar) are useful in orbital mechanics because these are the directions along which you want to thrust to minimize gravity losses. The blue arrows are useful because angular velocity points in this direction. The green arrows? They're useful for geometers and for describing vehicles flying through an atmosphere. They're not so useful in orbital mechanics, which is perhaps why there isn't a standard orbital mechanics name for this direction.

**Addendum**

When looking at the uncertainties in where a spacecraft is, those directions are oftentimes called along track (the red arrows), cross track (the blue arrows), and radial (the green arrows). One can look at "radial" as being either a bit of a misnomer or as being spot on correct. It's a misnomer in the sense that "radial" only points "radially" (toward / away from the planet in the case of a circular orbit. It's spot on in the sense that "radial" always points toward / away from the instantaneous center of curvature.

A related set of directions is the local vertical / local horizontal system, or LVLH for short. In this system, +Z points to the center of the Earth, +Y points opposite the orbital angular velocity, and +X completes the right hand coordinate system (i.e., $\hat x = \hat y \times \hat z$). This means that $\hat x$ points along the velocity vector in the case of a circular orbit. This labeling a bit arbitrary. The Clohessy-Wilshire equations use +X as pointing away from the Earth, +Z as pointing along the angular momentum vector, and +Y completing the right hand coordinate system. Either the LVLH frame or CW frame used to describe the orbital mechanics of a spacecraft rendezvousing with the ISS.

Comment: Yes, these 3 unit vectors were missing from answers, but how do you use them to name the 6  _orientations_ or _sides_ of an object in orbit? The same problem is with using radius vectors. How would one say, for example, _"please meet me at the `[?]` of the spacecraft"_? Surely, saying _"... `[negative normal facing side]` ..."_ sounds awkward?

Comment: For now, "I'll meet you in Zvezda" (or the Cupola, or Kibo, etc.) works just fine on the space station. The names of the modules don't change with orientation. There's no need to say "I'll meet you at X" in the Soyuz because there's no room in the Soyuz to get displaced.

Answer (score 5):

Green arrows are the "radius" vectors, the inner one points to the center of the planet.
Red arrows are velocity vectors. One of them will point in the direction of motion of the satellite, the other one, of course, in the opposite direction.
Blue arrows point in the direction of angular momentum, a quantity often labelled as "h".

The radius vector is often called the R-bar and the velocity vector the V-bar. You see this often in discussing about vehicles docking with the International Space Station. When they say a vehicle is making an R-bar approach, it is essentially "climbing up" the green arrow from below (so the ship is between the Earth and the station). V-bar approaches, if I'm not mistaken, typically take place from behind.

Source: AAE 532 at Purdue University, graduate level course in orbital mechanics.

Comment: The green arrows do not necessarily point to the center of the planet.  See my comments on PearsonArtPhoto's answer.

Comment: I'm assuming that the coordinate system is orthogonal and in the orbital plane, therefore if the red vector is pointing in the direction of velocity, the green vector must point to the center of the planet. If it's not orthogonal or not in the orbital plane, then it's just a random set of vectors that don't do anyone any good. Unless it's part of some weird scavenger hunt.

Comment: Eccentric orbits are ellipses with the planet's center at one of the foci.  At any given point on an ellipse, the line perpendicular to the tangent does not necessarily pass through either foci.  Your statement would be true for a perfectly circular orbit, but not the one pictured.

Comment: You're right, radius and velocity vectors are not perpendicular for an elliptical orbit, they're separated by the flight path angle gamma, which is computed using the "local horizon" which is an imaginary line that is perpendicular to the radius vector. Wow, I'm rustier than I thought!

Answer (score 3):

During the [Apollo moon landings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_OD2V6fMLQ), the astronauts referred to 'forward' and 'down' for the red and green vectors.
In the [Gemini 12 voice comms transcript](http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/mission_trans/GT12_TEC.PDF) (page 29 of a 500-page PDF), a maneuver is referred to as 'Posigrade up south' (in @Maxpm's diagram these directions refer to red, green, blue in that order).
The spacecraft attitude is described as 'yaw 1 right, pitch 4 up', and they refer to the 'thrusters aft'.

Answer (score 2):

There are specific body centered coordinate frames describing these directions.  The two most commonly used are:

RIC (aka UVW, RTN): Radial, In-Track, Cross-Track

Radial: In the direction of the satellite position vector

In-Track: Radial x Cross-Track (where 'x' denotes the vector cross product)

Cross-Track: Position x Velocity (aka angular momentum vector)

TNW: Tangential, Normal, W (angular momentum)

Tangential: In the direction of the Velocity vector

Normal: Normal to the velocity vector & down - W x T

W: P x V