# Do the Soyuz spacecraft bringing astronauts and supplies to the ISS use Ukraine-built Kurs systems?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, docking, kurs

A [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22041/#comment67353_23585) below [this great answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23585/12102) about the Kurs navigation and docking system linked to the following page on the Ukrainian company Elimz website:  http://www.elmiz.com/en/product/orbitalnyj-servis-eng/product/view/2/1

Is Elimz currently manufacturing Kurs systems and is Russia currently buying systems built in the Ukraine for ongoing Soyuz missions to the ISS? I ask partly because the respective governments have had some "disagreements" in recent years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Progress and Soyuz are now using a [new digital system called Kurs-NA](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/soyuz-ms-kurs-na.html) which is Russian-designed and -built.

Comment: Interesting, the article says the last flight of the Ukrainian system was in March 2016.

Comment: I saw a separate mention of Russian-made Kurs *antennas* used with the Ukrainian system; I wonder if they'd been reusing recovered Kurs modules for a while.

Comment: I do remember references to them cannibalizing used systems. I googled for it but couldn't find a reference.