# What's the shiny triangular feature on this Progress vehicle?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object, progress

Picture from [here](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2019/02/international-partners-progress-iss-funeral-plans/)

What's the shiny, slightly curved triangular plate with rails above it?

[image]

A larger version, cropped from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ISS-53_Progress_MS-07_cargo_craft_docked_to_Pirs.jpg), thanks to a comment by [ohsin](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/19014/ohsin).

[image]

Comment: ...or a protective cover of the sign that says "drill here"?

Comment: Hate to harsh your buzz :), but I looked at some old pics, and the thing was there on Progresses in 2011.

Comment: @OrganicMarble so it seems that the 2011 post-drilling vacuum patch held?

Comment: A better image(Progress 68) https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ISS-53_Progress_MS-07_cargo_craft_docked_to_Pirs.jpg It was present in 2000 https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/station/progress/html/iss001-324-002.html

Comment: A close up of Ohsin's image suggests it is an antenna.

Comment: Thermal exhaust port. For we all know what happens when you leave it open.

Comment: [This image][1] shows the same feature on an unlaunched Progress vehicle in the factory. It looks very much like a [triangular microstrip antenna for satellite comms][2]. The only supplier of microstrip patch antennas for space systems that I know of is USA-based AntDevCo in Las Cruces, NM. Looks like Ivan has started building his own, prolly as part of the EKTS. 


  [1]: http://spaceflight101.com/spacecraft/wp-content/uploads/sites/18/2015/12/photo_12-16-05-512x296.jpg
  [2]: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11277-016-3803-x

Comment: Same feature can be seen here on departing propulsion module (Progress-M derived) that delivered Poisk to ISS https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Propulsion_compartment_for_the_Poisk_module_departs.jpg

Comment: Not enough for an answer with authoritative quotes - it was on a French site thats since gone. It is indeed an antenna, it is the antenna for TORU, present on all Progress since M-15/1992. TORU was installed on Mir in Nov 1992 and they had been testing it since, with M-19 in 93. M-24 was the first full teleoperator docking of a Progress in Aug 94 after multiple collisions under automatic control. It has been installed on everything (Soyuz has a different antenna) since then.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby I'm confident that it's an antenna, and not for Kurs (https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23585/6944) TORU sounds likely, wish there was a good updated Soyuz description document.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - yup, TORU, not Kurs, which is quite well documented. I went through as many Russian docs as i could a long while back and although many mentions of installing and testing TORU, never any pictures. The first pic i know is of M-24 docked to Mir on STS-63 i think.